# Are there any references on linear algebra (module theory) over non unital rings?

Tags: ring-theory, modules

Are there any references on linear algebra (module theory) over non unital rings? What are the main differences with unital rings in that respect?

Comment: The main difference is that almost nothing works. The reason is simple: defining $rx=0$ for every $r\in R$ and every $x\in A$ defines an $R$-module structure on the abelian group $A$. Something better happens when you require that $RA=A$, in order that $A$ is a module.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this simple reason?

Comment: @PatrickSole doesn’t it seem a little bad that every Abelian group is a (nonunitary) module over every rng?  That’s certainly not the case for unitary modules.

Comment: Things break down severely. This is more or less the reason why I insist that rings should have multiplicative neutral elements :-)

Answer (score 4):

Maybe not exactly what you're looking for, but [these notes](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/files/QuillenModulesOverRngs.pdf) of Quillen say more about foundational matters regarding modules over non-unital rings than you probably thought possible!

He argues that the "correct" (I'm paraphrasing: he doesn't actually use that word) modules to consider are what he calls "firm modules".